# Sequelize asynchronous queries

Tags: javascript, database, asynchronous, sequelize.js

The terminology used on this question is probably not the most correct one but I hope you get the idea of what I'm asking.

If I have two asynchronous functions fetching and then updating a certain column from a certain row, is it possible for one of them to have fetched the non updated value? Or are the queries made in a way that they await for the other function to update the value before fetching it?

Comment: Use a promise, wait until it is done, make second call. Or change the api to return so you do not have to make two calls.

Comment: But these 2 asynchronous functions are not in the same file. They are a sort of event "listeners".

Comment: So you need to figure out a way to say X is done, fire Y. We can not see your code so we have no clue.

Comment: My question is poorly asked, I'll delete it, think about a better way to ask, then do it. Thanks for your help anyway @epascarello

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible for both conditions. If you want to fetch column first use and then update column try
let row = await model.Rows.findOne(where:condition);
let UpdateRow = await row.update(column);
in other case try this
let updateRow = await model.Rows.update('column'{ where:condition});
let row = await model.Rows.findOne({where:condition]);